# Get AudioInputStream from FFMPEG output

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to pipe output from FFMPEG to an AudioInputStream in Java. This is what I have so far:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-hide_banner", "no-stats", "-y", "-i", "song.wav", "-vn", "-q:a", "5", "-f", "mp3", "pipe:1").start();
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(process.getInputStream());
```

I thought I could just get the InputStream from the process and create and AudioInputStream from that, but this results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getFMT(WaveFileReader.java:234)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFileReader.java:150)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
    at com.darichey.argentumbot.ArgentumBot.onReady(ArgentumBot.java:68)
```

I'm not sure how I can do this properly.

Comment: what are these?? com.darichey.argentumbot com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader you are using some far off things?? we cannot help

Comment: What? com.darichey.argentumbot.ArgentumBot is the class in which the code I provided is being executed. And com.sun.media is part of the JDK... Not sure how that is defined as "far off"

Comment: @gpasch And anyways, if you think that using those is not good, I would like to know how to do it using other things.